# Vector iterator not being incremented

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, valgrind

I am trying to implement topological sort using dfs (as per CLRS).  I do get the required output displayed, but the program still runs and results in segmentation fault.  By using few print statements for debugging, I could make out that the for loop is never exited although it should (when **it==Edges.end()**).  However, also note that valgrind shows the error at

```
dfsVisit(it->first);
```

within within dfs().  What am I missing?  Why isn't the iterator incremented and the for loop exited?  And why different reason in valgrind?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<set>
#include<list>
#include<stack>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>

struct node
{
    int d, f, value;
};

std::vector< std::pair<node, node> > Edges;
std::vector< std::pair<node, node> >::iterator it;
bool *visited;
int N, myTime=0;
node node1, node2;
void dfsVisit(node);

void dfs()
{
    for(it=Edges.begin(); it!=Edges.end(); it++)
        if(it->first.value<N)
            if(!visited[it->first.value])
                dfsVisit(it->first);
}

void dfsVisit(node n)
{
    myTime++;                           //increment myTime
    n.d=myTime;                         //set the discovery time for node n

    if(n.value<N)
        if(visited[n.value])
            return;

    for(it=Edges.begin(); it!=Edges.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(it->second.value>=N)
            continue;
        printf("In the for loop!\n");
        if(it->first.value==n.value && !visited[it->second.value])
        {
            printf("it->first.value: %d\n",it->first.value+1);
            printf("it->second.value: %d\n",it->second.value+1);
            dfsVisit(it->second);
            printf("Inside for and if\n");
        }

        printf("Inside for but outside if!\n");
        printf("Edges.end()-it: %d\n",Edges.end()-it);
    }

    visited[n.value]=true;
    myTime++;
    n.f=myTime;

    printf("For node %d, discovery time and finishing time is: %d, %d", n.value, n.d, n.f);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int M, firstOfRule, secondOfRule, data, i;
    //node node1, node2;
    scanf("%d""%d",&N,&M);
    visited=new bool[N];

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        visited[i]=false;

    while(M--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&firstOfRule);
        scanf("%d",&secondOfRule);

        while(secondOfRule--)
        {
            scanf("%d",&data);
            node1.value=firstOfRule-1;
            node2.value=data-1;
            Edges.push_back(std::make_pair(node1,node2));
            printf("Pair: %d,%d\n", node1.value+1, node2.value+1);
        }
    }

    for(std::vector< std::pair<node, node> >::const_iterator it=Edges.begin(); it!=Edges.end(); ++it)
        printf("Connected %d and %d\n",it->first.value+1,it->second.value+1);

    dfs();

    return 0;
}
```

Output file is as below:

```
Pair: 1,2
Pair: 2,3
Connected 1 and 2
Connected 2 and 3
In the for loop!
it->first.value: 1
it->second.value: 2
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: 2
In the for loop!
it->first.value: 2
it->second.value: 3
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: 2
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: 1
For node 2, discovery time and finishing time is: 3, 4Inside for and if
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: 0                         //----->  Why doesn't it exit here?
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: -1
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: -2
In the for loop!
Inside for but outside if!
Edges.end()-it: -3
... and so on until the program crashes!
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Edges.end() - it == 0` indicates that `it == Edges.end()`. Then you do `++it` (loop iteration statement), which causes undefined behaviour .  `++it` is only valid if `it` is *before* the end.

Comment: When it == Edges.end() why doesn't the for condition become false and the loop exited?

Comment: It does (that happens after `Edges.end()it:1`). This is in a nested call to `dfsVisit`. Then execution moves up to the earlier `dfsVisit`, leaving `it == end` still.

Comment: I'm guessing you intended to have a local variable `it` for each `dfsVisit` function, instead of one global one. Otherwise it doesn't make much sense calling `dfsVisit` recursively, because then the first time that happens it will wreck the existing loop

Comment: Okay, I got your point to some extent.  So if I declare the vector iterator inside for, then it would do the trick, correct?  Currently it is declared to be global (and maybe is the cause of failure over multiple recursive calls)?

Comment: Yay! @M.M Your suggesting is just perfect.  I could execute it successfully by declaring it in a local context.  Please convert your comment into an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You were using a global iterator? wow...

Comment: @momo, yeah, my bad.  Your comment just adds more to my guilt. :)  Never mind, I will remember never to repeat this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `std::vector< std::pair<node, node> >::iterator it;` as a global variable.

But you are using it in a recursive function `dfsVisit`. This means that when a nested call to `dfsVisit` ends, it leaves `it == Edges.end()`. But then the earlier `dfsVisit` continues executing its loop, doing `++it` which causes undefined behaviour.

To fix this, make `it` be a local variable to the `dfsVisit` function.

*Note:* If your compiler supports C++11 you can avoid some typing and use `auto` to declare the iterator.